# cancel overlay popup view in android mapview while clicking outside of window

Tags: android

i am using mapview with overlay, here i tabbing the overlay item its shows information of particular overlay items... now i want to dismiss the information box while clicking out side of window..
here my sample code..

```
popUp = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.village_popupwindow, null,
                false);
final GeoPoint selectedPoint = item.getPoint();     
mapParams = new MapView.LayoutParams(500, 300, selectedPoint,130, -200, MapView.LayoutParams.CENTER);
                mapView.addView(popUp, mapParams);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.homeImage);
        TextView textTitle = (TextView) popUp.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
        TextView adress = (TextView) popUp.findViewById(R.id.text_plan);
        textTitle.setText(arrayListForAmenitiesDto.get(storeId).getName());
        adress.setText("Read more...");
```

any one know how to dismiss this popup layout?.. without using close button in popup layout... i want only dismiss the popup layout while clicking outside of popuplayout.

Comment: showing popup layout as dialog?

Answer (score 0):

you can remove that popup window by registering the **onTouchListener** to mapView. for e.g.

```
mapView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {          
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        try{
            //you can remove your popup here. hope this helps.
        }catch (Exception e) {}
      return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hai all i fixed the above issue, my answer is

```
otherHomesPlace.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onFocusChanged(ItemizedOverlay overlay,
                        OverlayItem newFocus) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("Focus changed"+otherHomesPlace.getFocus());
                    if(otherHomesPlace.getFocus()==null){
                    popUp.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    popUp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this code to dismis the popup window while outside touch

```
    popUp.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {            

        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            return true;
        }
    });
```